# Declaring method inside class

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

I am new to javascript object oriented programming. I wish to write a JS class which has some variable and methods.

I am trying this way:

```
function B(){
    function makeB()
    {
        alert('make B');
    }
}
var b = new B();
b.makeB();
```

It shows: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<B> has no method 'makeB'`

Can't I declare a function like this? But by simply adding `this` with the same, I am able to access it. Is it a local function within the variable.?

Apart from this, I tried this:

```
function B(){
    function call()
    {
        alert('B call');
    }
    this.makeB = function(){
        call();
        alert('makeB'); 
    }   
}
var b=new B();
b.makeB();
```

Using this, `makeB` can internally call `call` but if I try to access this using prototype it doesn't

```
function B(){
    function call()
    {
        alert('B call');
    }
}
B.prototype.makeB = function()
{
    call();
    alert('callB');
}
```

Here again I am not able to call `call` from `makeB` as if `call` is block specific function.

And what to do if I want any function to be private to a specific class and not to inherited by the child class. A method which can only be used by its object and not by object of inherited class.

```
function C(){}
C.prototype = new B();
C.prototype.constructor = C;
```

Say, I want object of `C` to call `makeB` but not `call`. In this case what should I do.?

Comment: JavaScript is prototype based and doesn't have a private modifier. Answers provided do not mention that using them makes your code harder to test re use and maintain. More on constructor function, prototype and why not to use closures to simulate private can be found here:http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to declare publicly accessible function inside JavaScript object you have to use `this`. By applying `this` you actually expose this function as a property of an object

```
function Person(first,last) {
   this.firstname = first;
   this.lastname = last;

   //private variable available only for person internal use
   var age = 25;

   //private function available only for person internal use
   var returnAge = function() {
      return age;
   };

   // public function available as person propert
   this.askAge = function()
   {
       return returnAge ;
   }
}

var john = new Person('John','Smith');
console.log(john.returnAge); // will return undefined
var johnsAge = john.askAge(); // will return 25
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to answer in the order of your questions...

In your first example, the function `call` is considered `private` and will not be accessible outside of the object scope itself.

For your second question, it will be `public` if you assign the function to `this` or what I like to do, create a "private" variable called **self** or sometimes on late nights I might call it **that**.  That way within other function calls and callbacks you always have scope of the object context.

```
 function B(){
   var self = this;
   function call()
   {
       alert('B call');
   }
   self.makeB = function() {
     call();
     alert('makeB'); 
   }   
 }
 var b=new B();
 b.makeB();
```

For the last I would say look at your inheritance chain and build your base with only the functions that will be shared by inheriting objects.

Hope this helps.